# How to convert QString to LPCSTR (Unicode)

Tags: c++, windows, qt, qt4, lpcstr

how can I convert QString to LPCSTR ?

How do I do it when #ifdef UNICODE is defined and when it isn't ?

Thanks very much :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I guess:

```
QString str("ddddd");
LPCSTR lstr = str.toStdString().c_str();
```

Comment: Thats if LPCSTR is const char*

Comment: `LPCSTR` is always defined as `char*`.  You're confusing that with `LPCTSTR` (note the **T**), which can map to either `const char*` or `const wchar_t*`, depending on if `UNICODE` is defined.

Answer (score 2):

`QString` can always hold Unicode; `LPCSTR` is never Unicode. This means that you do have to consider what to do with the characters that won't fit. This isn't a "which method to use" question, but a design question.

It's quite possible that in your specific case, you absolutely know that the `QString` only contaisn characters from your local "ANSI" codepage (also known as `ACP`). In that case, the correct function is `QString::toLocal8Bit ()`.

Alternatively, you might know that the `QString` only contains characters from Latin1 (ISO 8859-1). In that case, the correct function is `QString::toLatin1()`.

You could try to call `QString::toUtf8()`. This will always produce a valid byte array, even if the `QString` contained all Unicode characters. However, formally you can't point a `LPCSTR` to it: UTF-8 is not a valid `ACP` codepage. And presumably, you want this `LPCSTR` to pass to another function outside your control. It's likely that function won't expect UTF-8. If it expected Unicode at all, it would take a `LPCWSTR`.

Answer (score 0):

I found following solution from [here](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewreply/65924/) and it works flawlessly for me:

```
void fooSub(LPSTSTR X); // this is our function :-)

foo()
{
    QString text;
    if(sizeof(TCHAR) == 1)
        fooSub((LPCSTR)text.toLocal8Bit().constData()); // here you have to check, how to convert, you could also use utf8(), ...
    else
        fooSub((LPCWSTR)text.utf16());
}
```

Answer (score -6):

```
LPCSTR == const char *
```

it's not unicode, then

> LPCSTR s = (const char *)qtString;

Comment: You've misunderstood the question!

Comment: I dont think (const char*)qtString converts well.

Comment: AFAIK LPCSTR is defined as TCHAR*. And TCHAR is defined either as WCHAR or CHAR according to UNICODE setting.

Comment: declaration in WinNT.h: `typedef __nullterminated CONST CHAR *LPCSTR, *PCSTR;`

Comment: @Seba: That's `LPCTSTR` you're thinking of.

Comment: Sorry @Mark, @TonyK my mistake :)