# How to convert a Qt QString into an LPCTSTR on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, qt, qt5

I tried to open registry and modify it. This is how I open the registry:

```
HKEY hKey;
LPCTSTR subKey = TEXT("a registry subkey to be opened");
RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, subKey, 0, KEY_ALL_ACCESS , &hKey);
```

But here is a problem, I want to use a `QString` to change the subkey pragmatically. And put the `QString` like this:

```
QString subKeyString = QString("%1").arg(subKeyName);
LPCTSTR subKey = TEXT(subKeyString); //but it's not working here
```

I thought it's because I did not change the `QString` to `LPCTSTR`, I tried this solution, but still I can't figure out a way to put a custom `QString` into the `TEXT` macro. I am not quite sure the WinApi under the hood, I just tried what I could possibly do. 
Is there a way I can fix this problem?

**Edit:**
Here is how I convert `QString` to `LPCTSTR`:

```
QString testString = "converting QString to LPCSTR";
QByteArray testStringArr = testString.toLocal8Bit();
LPCSTR lp = LPCSTR(testStringArr.constData()); //the QString is converted to LPCTSTR
//but when I put the LPCSTR to the TEXT macro, the error is still there, like the next line below will not complie
LPCSTR lp = TEXT(LPCSTR(testStringArr.constData())); //This line will not work
```

Comment: Look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28090577/how-to-convert-qstring-in-qt5-to-lpcstr-in-visual-studio-2013

Comment: @infixed I did see some solutions like that, but I think that just convert `QString` to `LPCTSTR`, the problem for me is still there. I will edit my question, so you will know more clearly what error I encountered.

Comment: FYI the [QSettings](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsettings.html) class offers some integration between Qt and the Windows Registry, though it may be applicable to your situation.

Comment: @walkingTarget I tried using `QSettings` to modify the registry to what I need, but not working, except I use the native WinApi. So when I used the windows api, I met this problem. I edited my question, any solution?

Comment: `TEXT` is like `QStringLiteral`... the are to be used in the same circumstances: when you're passing in a string literal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `TEXT()` macro only works with compile-time literals, not with runtime data.  `TCHAR` and related APIs were designed to help people migrate their code from ANSI-based Win9x/ME to Unicode-based WinNT 4+, by mapping literals between `char` and `wchar_t`, and mapping function names between `A` and `W` variants. But those days are LONG gone.

The *correct* solution in this situation is to ignore `TCHAR` altogether and focus only on Unicode. A `QString` is a wrapper for a Unicode string. So use the Unicode-based Registry API functions only and pretend `TCHAR` doesn't exist.

On Windows, Unicode-based APIs expect UTF-16 encoded `wchar_t` strings. Use the `QString::toStdWString()` method to get a `std::wstring`, which is a C++ wrapper for a `wchar_t` string:

```
QString subKeyString = QString("%1").arg(subKeyName);
std::wstring subKey = subKeyString.toStdWString();
HKEY hKey;
RegOpenKeyExW(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, subKey.c_str(), 0, KEY_ALL_ACCESS, &hKey);
```

Alternatively, you can use the `QString::utf16()` method.  However, it returns a `const ushort*` pointer, so you will have to type-cast it to `const wchar_t*`:

```
QString subKeyString = QString("%1").arg(subKeyName);
LPCWSTR subKey = reinterpret_cast<LPCWSTR>(subKeyString.utf16());
HKEY hKey;
RegOpenKeyExW(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, subKey, 0, KEY_ALL_ACCESS, &hKey);
```

Comment: Doesn't Paul's answer avoid the need to construct a `std::wstring`? (In the specific case of wanting to call a Windows API, certainly, here might be other reasons why you would want a `std::wstring`).

Comment: @PaulSanders Win32 Unicode APIs expect `wchar_t*` strings. `std::wstring` is a `wchar_t*` string wrapper, so it "just works". `utf16()` will also work, only because the Win32 API uses `wchar_t*` for UTF-16 on Windows.

Comment: Sure, but still.  Anyway, posted my own modest contribution.

Answer (score 4):

`TEXT` macro was supposed to help maintaining both non-Unicode and Unicode versions of the app. Depending on whether `_UNICODE` (or `UNICODE`, don't remember already) is defined. `TEXT("foo")` would expand to either `L"foo"` or just `"foo"`. Similarly, `CreateWindow` will be either `CreateWindowW` that takes `WCHAR*` parameters or `CreateWindowA` that takes `CHAR*` parameters.

Considering it is 2018 now, I suggest you forget about `TEXT` macro and non-Unicode versions of the app. `QString::utf16()` will return UTF16 strings that WinAPI expects. If you compile with "Native wchar_t" compiler setting, you will need to cast what `utf16()` returns to `WCHAR*`. If "Native wchar_t` is turned off, it will work as is.

Comment: The Win32 API uses `UNICODE`, `TCHAR`, and `TEXT()`. The C runtime library uses `_UNICODE`, `_TCHAR`, and `_T()`, respectively.

Comment: @Remy I'm not sure I undersand that.  As Paul says, all you need to do (depending on your compiler (flags) is to cast the pointer returned by `QString::utf16()` to a `WCHAR *`.  Then you can pass it to any Win32 API call as you yourself show in your edit (and I would cast to `WCHAR *` rather than `wchar_t *` since that is how those API's are declared, although it doesn't actually matter in practice).

Comment: @PaulSanders that comment was in relation to the "Depending on whether `_UNICODE` (or `UNICODE`, don't remember already) is defined" portion of Paul's answer about the `TEXT` macro. That comment has nothing to do with Qt. Regarding Qt, if you use `QString::utf16()`, you have to type cast the returned pointer, as it is returned as a  `const ushort*` instead of a `const wchar_t*`, which is what the Win32 API is expecting.  Though both types are suitable for UTF-16 on Windows.

Comment: @PaulSanders as for "Native wchar_t", Paul is referring to MSVC's [`/Zc:wchar_t` parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/zc-wchar-t-wchar-t-is-native-type). `QString::utf16()` returns a `const ushort*` pointer. If `/Zc:wchar_t` is enabled, `wchar_t` is a distinct data type, so you have to type-cast the `const ushort*` to `const wchar_t*` to use it with the Win32 API. But if `/Zc:wchar_t` is disabled, `wchar_t` is just an alias for `ushort`, so you can use the `const ushort*` as-is with the Win32 API.

Comment: @Remy Oh right, sorry.  I thought your first comment was addressed to me but clearly, it isn't.  I will post a couple of utility functions which would take the pain out of the type casts.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a bit late to the party perhaps, but to build on the other two answers, something as simple as this would oil the wheels:

```
inline const WCHAR *QStoWCHAR (const QString& qs)
{
    return (const WCHAR *) qs.utf16 ();
}
```

And then you can do (for example):

```
RegOpenKeyExW (HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, QStoWCHAR (my_qstring), 0, KEY_ALL_ACCESS, &hKey);
```