# Converting QString to PCWSTR on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, qt

Why does the following code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51027141/how-to-convert-a-qt-qstring-into-an-lpctstr-on-windows) work:

```
QString username = "Bond";
std::wstring username = username.toStdWString();
PCWSTR username = username.c_str();
```

When the following does not:

```
QString username = "Bond";
PCWSTR username = username.toStdWString().c_str();
```

Comment: Nitpicking: You code will not compile in any case - you have duplicate names of variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The temporary object gets destroyed, the result of the `c_str()` is invalid after that point.

Comment: Legend! Even after years using C++ things like this continue to surprise

Answer (score 0):

The answer by `rpress` is of course correct. I am however using this conversion:

```
const QString usernameStr = "Bond";
auto usernameStrPtr = reinterpret_cast<PCWSTR>(usernameStr.utf16());
```

In most cases this will avoid one unnecessary allocation and conversion to `std:wstring`. I assume your expected coding is UTF16 anyway...

Comment: That one unecessary allocation is precisely what I was trying to avoid when I stumbled upon this problem, so this is a helpful way of doing it